# Как установить пакеты в dpkg busybox?

Tags: dpkg

Установил на смартфоне `busybox` со встроенным `dpkg` менеджером, но не могу через него ничего поставить, вернее пишет что установлено, но ничего из этого не могу запустить.

Сначала `dpkg` ругался на то что нет файла status в /var/lib/dpkg/ , затем папка info по этому же пути. Я создал структуру папок и пустой файл status так-же по требованию dpkg смонтировал корень на чтение и запись `busybox mount / -o remount,rw`.

В итоге установка началась и пакеты стали отображаться `dpkg -l`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при попытке запуска `debootstrap: not found`.

К сожалению только начал осваивать BusyBox и не совсем понимаю как происходит работа с пакетами или Applet'ми. Скажите, есть ли способ заставить это работать?

**Дополнительно:** проверил, пакеты действительно установились в папки:

```
usr/bin/wget
usr/sbin/debootstrap
usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabi - прочие зависимости
```

Но запустить все равно не удается.

Comment: А вы проверяли, что переменная окружения PATH содержит в себе тот каталог, в который был установлен исполняемый файл debootstrap?

Comment: @andreymal нет, не проверял. Честно, не уверен что понимаю. Т.е. когда я произвожу вызов установленного пакета окружение не может понять где находится этот пакет, верно? пробовал даже так: busybox debootstrap и просто название пакета, результат один